# Keep WhatsApp backup in Google Drive

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-drive

In November 12th 2018 WhatsApp will be [deleting old backups](https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/whatsapp-will-delete-your-old-messages-unless-you-backup-to-google-drive-by-12-november_uk_5b7d02a0e4b07295150e1537) in Google Drive, and they will take no space in your Google drive.

I don't mind my backups taking space in Google Drive, but I do not want them deleted. Is there any way to preserve them?

Comment: I have switched google accounts, and I cannot find a way to keep that backup in that Google account alive without buying a new phone.

Comment: You need to export your messages and save them on your own...